# How can I password-protect a page/action with only a password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to require that authenticated users provide a password to access a certain page/action.

I know that RoR has **authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic()** that can be used to protect an action but that requires that a name and password be entered and I'm only interested in requiring a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can always leave user blank.

If it isn't an option I have some bad news - browser **will always** ask for user and password when using http basic authentication.

However there are some different options:

- providing some key in url that works as password (quite unsecure)
- login box with password field only, that (when password is correct) set `session[:auth] = true`. And appropriate `before_filter` in your `ApplicationController`.
- Normak authentication but with one field (password only) - I'm not sure if it would be good.

I think second option would be best here (if of course, leaving http basic auth login/password box isn't an option).

Comment: For now using `before_filter :basic_authenticate` and in basic_authenticate I'm ignoring the username so any username works. Not great but super simple.